# C# Using a list of objects to populate combobox and keeping object properties accessible

Tags: c#, list, object, combobox, populate

I'm having some difficulty populating a combobox with the values inside a list.
The list contains the following.

```
public List<Classroom> classes= new List<Classroom>();
```

CONTAINS:

```
public List<Students> Members{ get;}

public Classroom(string naam, string code, int maxPersonen)
{
    Name= name;
    Code = code;
    MaxPeople= maxpeople;
    Members= new List<Members>();
}
```

i'm trying to populate my combobox with `List` classes and show each of these classes as following (currently using this):

```
foreach(Classroom classrooom in repository.classes)
{
    cmbClass.Items.Add(classroom.Name + " (" + classroom.Code + ")");
}
```

I want to visually show them like this, but still be able to access every other property of the classroom that is selected (when using).

Hope this is clear enough to understand!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to bind the list as a datasource to the combobox rather than adding one by one. And, add read only property **DisplayName** to classroom to return **Name + " (" + Code + ")"** to use it as a display value. You can add datasource, set display value and the selected item property will return the object.

```
    cmbClass.DataSource = classes;
    cmbClass.DisplayMember = classroom.DisplayName;
```

Reference - ComboBox Class:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I suppose i'll have to create an instance of Class called classroom to folow your example. Also i'm getting an error on the Valuemember bit; Cannot implicitly convert type 'Class' to 'string'.
ps. I suppose it's cmbClass.Datasource instead of ItemsSource?

Comment: You already have instances of classroom in the list. And, yes it's DataSource property (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8160f6f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). All you need to do is assign the DataSource and DisplayMember properties. ValueMember property isn't needed. Selected item will return the object directly.

Comment: I'm not completely getting it. Seeing as the name 'classroom' was what i used to fill my comboboxes in my foreach. Since i don't need the foreach for your method, i don't have 'classroom' to call on to.

Comment: Instead of classroom.Displayname, use cmbClass.DisplayMember = "DisplayName"; and your method works perfectly! Thanks alot!

Comment: You are welcome Kevin! Glad that it helped. I recently started contributing on StackOverflow and it really feels good that I was able to help you!

Comment: @AbhijitAnnaldas how can we access the properties of the selected class object?