# binding <int,object> dictionary to a Combobox

Tags: c#, combobox, datasource

I have a combobox with an `<int, Object>` dictionary bound to it. 
Now the combobox should display the "Name" property of the object.
Using the DrawItem event of the ComboBox I managed to get the dropdown part to display the Name property.
The problem is, once an item is selected, the textfield shows the object.ToString() text.
Is there a way to have the textfield show the "Name" property of the selected Item?

**EDIT:**

This is an example code of the problem

```
class Class1
{
    private ComboBox CB;
    private Dictionary<int, Obj> ObjList;
    private Obj ObjA;
    private Obj ObjB;
    private BindingSource BS;


    public Class1(ComboBox cb)
    {
        CB = cb;
        CB.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;
        CB.DrawItem += CB_DrawItem;

        ObjList = new Dictionary<int, Obj>();

        ObjA = new Obj();
        ObjA.Name = "Name A";
        ObjB = new Obj();
        ObjB.Name = "Name B";
        ObjList.Add(1, ObjA);
        ObjList.Add(2, ObjB);

        BS = new BindingSource(ObjList, null);
        BS.ResetBindings(false);
        CB.DataSource = BS;
        CB.Update();

    }

    private void CB_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox lst = sender as ComboBox;
        if (e.Index >= 0)
        {
            KeyValuePair<int, Obj> kv = (KeyValuePair<int, Obj>)lst.Items[e.Index];
            var o = kv.Value;

            e.DrawBackground();
            if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(o.Name, CB.Font, SystemBrushes.HighlightText, new RectangleF(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height));
            }
            else
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(o.Name, CB.Font, SystemBrushes.ControlText, new RectangleF(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height));
            }
            e.DrawFocusRectangle();
        }
    }

    internal class Obj
    {
        public string Name;
    }
}
```

And this is a screenshot of the combobox:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wtQo.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Using a list of objects to populate combobox and keeping object properties accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34250770/c-sharp-using-a-list-of-objects-to-populate-combobox-and-keeping-object-properti)

Comment: Is this WPF or Forms?

Comment: Hi Kurakura, this is Forms, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Previous answer didn't solve the problem

Thanks for adding your code I've tried it and come up with something that works (for me at least) If you override the .ToString() method in your Obj like so

```
internal class Obj
{
 public string Name;

 public override string ToString()
  {
    return Name;
  }
}
```

then what you get is a list that looks like this:

> [1, Name A]
>
> [2, Name B]

But that isn't entirely what you want (I don't think) but if you add this line here

```
BS = new BindingSource(ObjList, null);
BS.ResetBindings(false);
CB.DataSource = BS;
CB.DisplayMember = "Value";   // Add this line here
CB.Update();
```

It works like you want, if your CB_DrawItem function was a workaround then you can also then remove it along with these two lines:

```
 CB.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;
 CB.DrawItem += CB_DrawItem;
```

Here's a pic to show the result (wanted it as a link like yours but not sure how to do that)
[image: Preview Pic]

Comment: Hi Rowie, Thanks for helping! I have done that but this leaves me with an empty textbox somhow.

Comment: No sorry that's not true, if I set comboBox1.Text to a value, it still shows the object.ToString() value...it just doesn't show what i assign to it....

Comment: Apologies I thought that would work.  While I look into this, do you need the ToString() for anything else or can that be overriden?

Comment: Thanks Rowie!! That did the trick. never thought of overriding the ToString() method!

Comment: You're welcome! glad to help, incidently while trying to figure it out I had the opposite problem in that I got names to show no problem but had more trouble filling the ComboBox.  Funny how some things that you expect to work, don't and visa versa.  I was surprised how simple the actual answer was, learning experience for us both :)